# Azure Logic Apps parameters - how to use it?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

For a few weeks now, there is a new "Parameter" section in the Designer of Logic Apps. We can create parameters and use these parameters in the Logic Apps:
[image]

Unfortunately, there are two things that are missing (or not working yet):

- We are not able to set the "current value" of a parameter (as shown below, the field Actual Value is grayed)
  [image]
- When we export the Logic App as an ARM template, parameters are not used in the ARM template as ARM parameters.

Am I missing something or is it just due to the fact that there are features not yet deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not either sure how default/actual values should work in the Logic App designer  but for the export of the ARM template with the (designer) parameters I'm using the last build of [LogicAppTemplateCreator](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator)  and it works for me.

The template snippet contains "paramDateFrom" parameter with its default value and it is used in the parameters section of ARM:

```
    ...
    "paramDateFrom": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "2019-12-19"
  }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
  "dependsOn": [],
  "properties": {
    "definition": {
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "DateFrom": {
          "defaultValue": "[parameters('paramDateFrom')]",
          "type": "String"
        }
      },
      ...
```

The template parameters file contains the actual value:

```
  ...
  "parameters": {
  "paramDateFrom": {
  "value": "2019-12-20"
}
```